# Application_BeginRequest not firing when there is no extension

Tags: c#, asp.net

Application_BeginRequest fires when I start debugging. Then, if I click a link like "/home", I get a 404 error right away, Application_BeginRequest is not even fired, but if I add ".aspx", it's fired. Odd thing is, it was working last week.

Comment: OK... and what is the question again?

Comment: Why isn't it firing when there is no extension? it was firing last week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the configuration issue of your application. IIS is not handling extentionless urls correctly.

try adding following entry to your web.config file:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Also there's a hotfix from Microsoft available here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

I've installed that one some time ago and problems with `WebApi` requests(extentionless) were gone.

Comment: I already tried the <modules> change, it didn't work. I don't have access to the IIS server, but my website published in PROD still works without extensions, but the published "test" version of the website doesn't. And locally, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok... the Application_BeginRequest started working again after I commented the line "txtname.focus()" and uncommented it. But now it's my requiredfield validators that aren't working anymore. I guess my computer is haunted. Thanks guys for the answers